# "Synchronizing" a render pass layout transition with a semaphore in Acquire-Present scenario in Vulkan

Tags: synchronization, vulkan, memory-model

So there is this official example https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples#combined-graphicspresent-queue:

```
/* Only need a dependency coming in to ensure that the first
   layout transition happens at the right time.
   Second external dependency is implied by having a different
   finalLayout and subpass layout. */
VkSubpassDependency dependency = {
    .srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
    .dstSubpass = 0,
    // .srcStageMask needs to be a part of pWaitDstStageMask in the WSI semaphore.
    .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    .srcAccessMask = 0,
    .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
    .dependencyFlags = 0};
```

Could someone please provide me with relevant sections in the specification that combined guarantee (constitute a chain of reasoning) that with such a dependency layout transition will happen not until the queue's wait semaphore (image acquired) is signaled?

Particularly I can't find how to interpret this "dependency from that same stage to itself".

To be clear. I've found a lot of places that seem to be relevant here. I'm reading docs for over a month now but I'm struggling to find coherence in them.

For example when (according to the specification) an availability operation does happen? When relevant memory dependency operation was submitted (as in submission order)? If yes than when the subpass dependency is submitted? Or is it somewhere between source scope instructions and destination scope instruction (like in `If srcSubpass is equal to VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, the first synchronization scope includes commands that occur earlier in submission order than the vkCmdBeginRenderPass`). And if yes what instructions the `srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` in the above example is referring to?

**EDIT after krOoze's answer**

I thought I'll write here. One because it's too long for a comment and two because I believe it may be useful for others.

I admit, I misinterpreted the part about the execution dependency chain in the spec.

So to sum it up. To define the mechanism in question in terms of the Specification we have what follows:

1. The *waiting on semaphore* operation *happens-before* the subpass dependency operation (here I have some trouble actually):

   > 6.4.2. Semaphore Waiting<sup>*</sup>
   >   The semaphore wait operation happens-after the first set of operations in the execution dependency, and happens-before the second set of operations in the execution dependency.

   But how to be sure that our subpass dependency operation is in the second set? It is in the same batch, it doesn't have defined submission order with regard to a subpass dependency (at least I cannot see one) and the definition of the semaphore second synchronisation scope isn't helpful because our subpass dependency doesn't happen on the VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT pipeline stage (and it's the limitation of the second synchronisation scope in case of vkQueueSubmit). What's more synchronisation scope doesn't define the second set of operations anyway. It's a distinct term. But I've found one more statement that may be helpful here (well, if we'll agree that a subpass dependency is a part of a work item):

   > 4.3.5. Queue Submission
   >   Each batch consists of three distinct parts:
   >
   > 1. Zero or more semaphores to wait on ***before execution*** of the rest of the batch.
   > 2. Zero or more work items to execute.
   > 3. Zero or more semaphores to signal upon completion of the work items.

   And we need to be sure of this ordering to construct the execution dependency chain:
2. Waiting on the semaphore and the subpass dependency constitute an execution dependency chain according to:

   > 6.1. Execution and Memory Dependencies
   >   An execution dependency chain is a **sequence of execution dependencies** that form a happens-before relation between the first dependency’s A' and the final dependency’s B'. For each **consecutive** pair of execution dependencies, a chain exists if the intersection of B<sub>S</sub> in the first dependency and A<sub>S</sub> in the second dependency is not an empty set.

   (see krOoze's answer for details)

   From this we know that the destination scope of our subpass dependency will *happen-after* signaling the semaphore (a signal operation is in the source scope of the semaphore wait operation).
   Now we should be fine with the layout transition rule:
3. Layout transition happens-after the availability operation for our subpass dependency:

   > 7.1. Render Pass Creation
   >   Automatic layout transitions away from initialLayout **happens-after the availability operations** for all dependencies with a srcSubpass equal to VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, where dstSubpass uses the attachment that will be transitioned.

   To be honest I'm still missing the ordering between signaling the semaphore and the availability operation part in the spec but I think it could be assumed.
   (the above would work because an availability operation is part of the memory dependency operation:

   > An operation that performs a memory dependency generates:
   >   • An availability operation with source scope of all writes in the first access scope of the dependency and a destination scope of the device domain.

   well our first access scope is empty but still it's an availability operation, right?)

There's also this statement:

> For attachments however, subpass dependencies work more like a VkImageMemoryBarrier defined similarly to the VkMemoryBarrier above, the queue family indices set to VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED, and layouts as follows:
>   • The equivalent to oldLayout is the attachment’s layout according to the subpass description for srcSubpass.
>   • The equivalent to newLayout is the attachment’s layout according to the subpass description for dstSubpass.

...which brings another scope to analyse but my head aches already. I'll be more than happy to edit this more when I got some review of the above thoughts.

<sup>*</sup>All the spec quotes from "Vulkan® 1.2.132 - A Specification (with all registered Vulkan extensions)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I go over this a bit at [krOoze/Hello_Triangle/doc](https://github.com/krOoze/Hello_Triangle/tree/master/doc). What is supposed to happen in this scenario is:

[image]

> Particularly I can't find how to interpret this "dependency from that same stage to itself".

Now, lets first take care of this issue. This is what I like to call [cart-before-horse intuition of the synchronization system](https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/f2yabw/how_does_pwaitdststagemask_member_work_in/).

You do **not** "synchronize stages" or something like that. That is intuition that will only cause you confusion. You synchronize scopes.

People also confuse a pipeline with a flow-chart. There is a huge intuition difference. In flow-chart, you start at a start, then you go over all the stages in order, then you are finished and forever done. That is **not** what pipeline is. It never starts, and never finishes. Pipeline just is. It is like a desktop game board. You stuff commands through the pipeline, and **they** go through the stages like pegs on the board.

A synchronization command is something that introduces a dependency between two things: between the *source synchronization scope* and *destination synchronization scope*. It guarantees the src scope happens-before the dst scope.

A *scope* is some subset of queue operations, and at what stage they currently their execution can be at.

So, with this better intuition,

```
    .srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
    .dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
```

is a perfectly normal thing to do. It means the commands in the source scope (for a barrier, the commands recorded earlier, or more formally those "earlier in submission order") reached `COLOR_ATTACHMENT` stage, before any commands in the destination scope reached `COLOR_ATTACHMENT` stage. (In contrast, **without** the dependendency it would mean that any command can be at any stage in its execution at any given time).

> For example when (according to the specification) an availability operation does happen.

These are somewhat inserted in the dependency the barrier defines. Assuming you included a *memory dependency* in your barrier.

The *availability operation* (if any) happens-after the source synchronization scope. Then happens the layout transition (if any). Then happens the *visibility op* (if any). And only after then can the destination synchronization scope execute.

> Could someone please provide me with relevant sections in the specification that combined guarantee (constitute a chain of reasoning)

I just want to pat you on the head right now for wanting the authoritative information... :D

So, you need to know the formalism and the nomenclature. It is the thing all the synchronization primitives are described with. It is only one-page but relatively hard read. I tried explain the important parts above. I am not gonna quote it here, it is the [6.1. Execution and Memory Dependencies](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-dependencies) chapter.

Now, semaphore wait has its own chapter. It is important to note it behaves bit differently for other commands than for `vkQueueSubmit`(which gets annoying). Anyway ([6.4.2. Semaphore Waiting](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-semaphores-waiting)):

> The second synchronization scope includes every command submitted in the same batch. In the case of `vkQueueSubmit`, the second synchronization scope is limited to operations on the pipeline stages determined by the *destination stage mask* specified by the corresponding element of `pWaitDstStageMask`. Also, in the case of `vkQueueSubmit`, the second synchronization scope additionally includes all commands that occur later in *submission order*.
>
> The second *access scope* includes all memory access performed by the device.

*Batch* (for `vkQueueSubmit`) is the single `VkSubmitInfo`. *Submission order* also has its own chapter; basically it means "all the other Batches that are later in the submission array, as well as any future `vkQueueSubmit` on the same queue too".

So, this means: "if you wait on a semaphore, all commands in the `VkSubmitInfo` can reach a `pWaitDstStageMask` stage only after the semaphore was signaled".

Now it is important to understand what a Render Pass does. Apart from the recorded commands, it has other "synchronizables": the automatic layout transitions, the load operations, and the store operations.

The automatic layout transition:

> Automatic layout transitions away from `initialLayout` happens-after the *availability operations* for all dependencies with a srcSubpass equal to `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`, where dstSubpass uses the attachment that will be transitioned
>
> Automatic layout transitions into the layout used in a subpass happen-before the *visibility operations* for all dependencies with that subpass as the `dstSubpass`.

So in simple terms, layout transition is sneaked in inside the dependency that the `VkSubpassDependency` you list defines. It happens after the `.srcStageMask` with `.srcAccessMask`. And it happens before the `.dstSubpass` and `.dstStageMask` with `.dstAccessMask`.

The load op:

> The load operation for each sample in an attachment happens-before any recorded command which accesses the sample in the first subpass where the attachment is used. [...] Load operations for attachments with a color format execute in the `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` pipeline stage.
>
> `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD` [...] For attachments with a color format, this uses the access type `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT`.
>
> `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR`(or `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE`) [...] For attachments with a color format, this uses the access type `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT`.

The load op happens as part of the first subpass that uses the attachment (your `.dstSubpass`). And the above unambiguously determines your `.dstStageMask` and `.dstAccessMask`)

Now, it comes to our choice of `pWaitDstStageMask` and `.srcStageMask` and `.srcAccessMask`. You list it is `pWaitDstStageMask = COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT`, `.srcStageMask = COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT` and `.srcAccessMask = 0`.

The Semaphore wait operation has to happen-before the `VkSubpassDependency` stuff. This is specified as *dependency chain*:

> An execution dependency chain is a sequence of execution dependencies that form a happens-before relation between the first dependency’s **A'** and the final dependency’s **B'**. For each consecutive pair of execution dependencies, a chain exists if the intersection of **B<sub>S</sub>** in the first dependency and **A<sub>S</sub>** in the second dependency is not an empty set.

I.e. two subsequent synch primitives also do synch with each other and form a transitional property. Our **A'** here is the semaphore signal, and our **B'** here is the dst scope of the `VkSubpassDependency`. Our **B<sub>S</sub>** here is the semaphore dst scope, i.e. `pWaitDstStageMask`. And our **A<sub>S</sub>** is the src scope of our `VkSubpassDependency`.

So our `pWaitDstStageMask` intersection with `.srcStageMask` is still `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT`. Therefore a dependency chain is formed, that guarantees the semaphore signal happens-before the `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT` of the commands in the `0` subpass of the render pass.

Now, putting it all together: the semaphore signal from `vkAcquireNextImage` makes the swapchain image *available from* the read of the presentation engine. The semaphore wait in `vkQueueSubmit` makes the swapchain image *visible to* all commands in the Batch limited to `COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT`. The `VkSubpassDependency` chains to that semaphore wait. The image is still *visible to*, so no additional memory dependency is needed and so our `.srcAccessMask` is `0`. The layout transition writes the image and makes it (implicitly) *available from* the layout transition and *visible to* whatever the `.dst*` was provided to the `VkSubpassDependency`.

Comment: That is quite an answer! Thank you, though I did not get the part about patting my head. ;)
I've updated my answer. Will you be able to take a look at it once more?

Comment: *my qustion obviously

Comment: @listerreg TBH many people just want to be spoon-fed by the knowledge-peddling middle-men with bottled knowledge bits. Which makes it nice to see someone straight up ask for the spec quotes like a man. :p That makes me feel more like helping a person fish, rather than giving them a fish, as the saying goes. Careful though not to abuse the SO system too much; this is not reddit. Keep the questions atomic if you can, and create new ones as needed. I will clarify what I can in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I know it’s not reddit. I strongly believe it’s still the same question. :) Oh, and this “dependency from that same stage to itself” is a quote from the 6.4.2. Semaphore Waiting part of the spec.

Comment: hold on (in case you were in the middle of writing) I've found big flaw in my reasoning I need to correct.

Comment: @listerreg Nah, I haven't had time to read it yet. But extensive Q editing is a red flag, which is what I am saying. I will take your word on it that it does not change or extend the nature of the Q.

Comment: Done. Yeah, I know SO has plenty of red flags and no one will delete my lame question from before ages but what can I do? I really did try to solve the problem with all the others means and invested a lot of my time into it. Asking on SO was the last thing I did and I'm really grateful for the time you're spending writing answers.

Comment: ad Q.1 I think I covered that. It is a dependency chain. The sentence you quote says the Semaphore gets unsignaled between the src and dst scope that are specified above it. 4.3.5. Queue Submission chapter makes just an introduction to the mechanism, and I would not try to read too much between the lines of that chapter.

Comment: ad Q.2 Q.3: That is because the availability (a memory dependency; which I omitted to preserve some semblance of brevity) is also defined in terms of the execution dependency chain. IMO, it is bit awkward and could lead exactly to this kind of misinterpretation, and I am in the process to make an Issue to spec for this to be clarified.

Comment: "well our first access scope is empty but still it's an availability operation, right?" I think that is a nill distinction. You could think of it that it is, or you could think of it that the availability is skipped. If you think it matters somewhere, let me know. BTW this is why I instead prefer to say "available from" instead of just "available". And in our case, the access mask makes things "available from" nothing. But the image is already "available from" by the semaphore signal. And it is already "visible to" the whole batch limited to `pWaitDstStageMask` by the Semaphore wait.

Comment: The last Quote in the Q is just a note. Do not try to read too much into it. Its only point is to say subpass dependencies are esentially the same thing as barriers.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd leave it for now and delve further into the tutorial and Pawel's book. It's getting a bit academic for someone without a CG background. If you have any suggestions what to change/delete in my question to be most useful let me know or feel free to edit it.

Comment: @listerreg It is relatively new to everyone. It is not like Barriers are common part of CG education. I am gonna blame the spec here. The case you bring up indeed gets convoluted to explain formally.

Answer (score 1):

*All the specs quoted from "Vulkan® 1.2.169 - A Specification (with all registered Vulkan extensions)".*

Q:

> Particularly I can't find how to interpret this "dependency from that same stage to itself".

A:

In [7.4.2. Semaphore Waiting](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-semaphores-waiting) , it provides an example in the note section.

> If an image layout transition needs to be performed on a presentable image before it is used in a framebuffer, that **can** be performed as the first operation submitted to the queue after acquiring the image, and **should** not prevent other work from overlapping with the presentation operation. For example, a `VkImageMemoryBarrier` could use:
>
> - `srcStageMask` = `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`
> - `srcAccessMask` = 0
> - `dstStageMask` = `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`
> - `dstAccessMask` = `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT` | `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT`.
> - `oldLayout` = `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR`
> - `newLayout` = `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL`

As subpass dependencies work like a [VkImageMemoryBarrier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkImageMemoryBarrier) according to the note section with respect to [VkSubpassDependency](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkSubpassDependency),

> For non-attachment resources, the memory dependency expressed by subpass dependency is nearly identical to that of a [VkMemoryBarrier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkMemoryBarrier) ...
>
> For attachments however, subpass dependencies work more like a [VkImageMemoryBarrier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkImageMemoryBarrier) defined similarly to the [VkMemoryBarrier](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkMemoryBarrier) above ...

the further notes about the example can answer part of the question.

> This barrier accomplishes a dependency chain between previous presentation operations and subsequent color attachment output operations, with the layout transition performed in between, and does not introduce a dependency between previous work and any vertex processing stages. More precisely, the semaphore signals after the presentation operation completes, the semaphore wait stalls the `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` stage, and there is a dependency from that same stage to itself with the layout transition performed in between.