# When using VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, srcSubpass represents whose stage?

Tags: synchronization, semaphore, vulkan

**The spec says:** *If srcSubpass is equal to `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`, the first synchronization scope includes commands that occur earlier in submission order than the `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` used to begin the render pass instance.*

As I understand, if the subpass recorded instruction in **buffA**, then `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` does not contain the instruction in buffA. For the first synchronization range, `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` only contains the instruction before **buffA** in the queue.That is, if `srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`, the `srcStageMask` is not contains the pipeline stage of **buffA**, It's the previous.

If `pWaitDstStageMask=VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT` is set, When `vkQueueSubmit` is called, the subpass is executed immediately, If `srcStageMask` is not the output stage of the subpass, Layout transitions should happen immediately, Because the previous output stage has been completed, But it's not.

I know that writing the attachment needs to wait for Layout conversion , and the Layout conversion can only be carried out after PE reads it. I also know that the subpass will wait for PE semaphore in the output stage, which is memory dependent.

Where I'm confused is does `srcSubpass` include the stage of the subpass itself?
If yes, then **`srcSubpass = pWaitDstStageMask = output stage of this subpass buffA`**, then everything should be clear. But the spec says that `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` does not contain the instructions contained in subpass...

I want to know whether `srcSubpass` contains the stage of subpass itself. Is the description of the spec inaccurate? Or is there something wrong with my understanding?

[image]

Comment: "*As I understand*" The specification never once mentioned command buffers. It said "earlier in submission order". That doesn't really care about CBs. Also, your question seems to boil down to "do sources include their destinations?" Which... no, they do not.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas:
Ah, if not, the `VkSubpassDependency` should immediately do the Layout transformation when `submit` executes, since the previous output stage on the queue may have completed. But no, it doesn't start converting until this subpass reaches the output stage. Why?

Comment: Your descriptions seem a bit confused. You say "when `submit` executes", but like, what does that *mean*? "Submit" doesn't "execute"; *commands* execute when you issue a submit call that contains those commands. And they execute with respect to submission order, dependency chains, and everything else in Chapter 7 of the specification. Nothing ever happens "immediately" when you submit anything.

Comment: Also, what is "buffA"? Is that a command buffer, a render pass instance, or something else?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Ah, I'm talking about [this example](https://vkguide.dev/docs/chapter_2), one subpass, `srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`. buffA is the subpass cbs. I mean when submit calls, The cbs of the subpass will enter the graph queue, subpass begins its rendering process. VkSubpassDependency sets the timing of the Layout transition.If srcStageMask refers the stage before this subpass in the queue, Why does the Layout transition occur in the output stage of this subpass? The conditions specified by srcStageMask have probably been met and should be transition at any time.

Comment: I don't know what a "cbs" is. Is that a command buffer? Perhaps, a secondary command buffer? I searched for this acronym in the linked tutorial but couldn't find it. "*Why does the Layout transition occur in the output stage of this subpass?*" They do not "occur in" any stage. The transitions happen *between* the source and destination stages.

Comment: @NicolBolas: In order to make the question clear, I submitted a picture in the question. Suppose we have two frames of data in our graph queue, each containing a single subpass. Layout transition occur between src and dst. For this example, does the src of frame2 refer to the red arrow (output stage of Frame1) location? If so, the Layout transition of frame2 should occur in the blue arrow area, but in fact the transition occur in the green arrow position(output stage of frame2), Isn't the blue arrow area between src and dst?

Comment: "*but in fact the transition occur in the green arrow position*" How do you know that? There is nothing which has well-defined behavior that could possibly tell you exactly when a layout transition occurs.

Comment: Subpasses and Pipeline stages are two unrelated concepts, so I don't fundamentally understand the question. Short answer is: `srcSubpass` does not represent any stage, becuase it is a Subpass, not a Stage. Stage is provided via `srcStageMask` parameter.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339191/synchronizing-a-render-pass-layout-transition-with-a-semaphore-in-acquire-pres) you have some indepth exploration on how the sync of typical tutorial app works, which may clear some conceptual misunderstandings.