# Synchronizing layout transition initialLayout in VkAttachmentDescription

Tags: vulkan

I'm learning from the tutorial https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Render_passes.
I have a question: do I need to synchronize the layout transition, which redraws the image layout in the initialLayout at the beginning of the Render pass. The tutorial says Undefined so there will be no transition, because any layout is fine, but what if initialLayout was a different value, would it be necessary to synchronize the start of render pass with getting the image from swap chain, if yes, how?

Comment: "*The tutorial says Undefined so there will be no transition*" It says no such thing. There will be a layout transition; what there won't be is a preservation of the contents. This has nothing to do with any need for synchronization with anything else.

Comment: Nicol Bolas, if there is no content saving, does that mean that the image will not change its layout? And if initial layout equals VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL for example, then in theory when getting image from swapchain it will have this layout and therefore we should wait for image from swapchain or I don't understand something?

Comment: Nicol Bolas, I read the specs and I think I misunderstood the initial layout. As I understand it, the initial layout specifies the layout of the image that render pass will work with, not the layout to which it should lead the image in the beginning. Is this correct?

Comment: Yea. `initialLayout` tells Vulkan in which layout it will already find the image in. `UNDEFINED` pretty much guarantees there **will** be a layout transition. If `initialLayout` differs from first `layout`, then layout transition is performed.

Comment: krOoze, thanks. In that case, if the first layout is different from the initial layout and we get an image from a swap chain, for example, do we need to synchronize the layout transition with the image from the swap chain? If so, how?

Comment: Topic of some internal debate. But until that comes to some conclusion, layout transition is considered a write access as any other. Swapchain acquire tells you when it is finished accessing the image via the semaphore or fence. Layout transition is specified to happen relative to the `VkSubpassDependency` parameters. And afterwards the Load Operation is specified to happen in the stages and access masks stated in the specification; e.g. `STAGE_COLOR` for color attachments and `WRITE` for `CLEAR` op.

Comment: Extended answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339191/synchronizing-a-render-pass-layout-transition-with-a-semaphore-in-acquire-pres